# passing parameter in http header with REST service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jersey

Right now i'm using java to build rest service, and trying to use spring security to securing my service. 
I have a few parameter that server needs to process the service (ex: application ID, username, password, consumer ID) . For username and password, I put in on http header "authorization", encoded with base64. Is there a way to put another parameters above (ex. AppID, consID) into http header? 
Some sample of code would help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put whatever you want in a whatever header you like. You can create custom headers. So you can have a `App-Id` header where you pass the appId. Alternatively you can pass those as parameters in the URL. That way you'll get rid of the option that some (stupid) proxy trims your headers.

Btw, I would suggest not to send the password, unless you are using https. Generally, I can recommend two similar scenarios:

- use OAuth - let the user grant access to the API client via the OAuth dance. The client ends up with a token which it uses on each request.
- use a custom, simplified token scheme - login once (with username and password, over https), and send a short-lived token in response. Each subsequent request can be made over an unsecured connection by providing the token, and (optionally) some HMAC of the request parameters, using a consumer secret as a key, so that you can verify the client is legit.

Comment: Thanks @bozho, I prefer the second of your opinion, while still configure how to use oauth